# Weird matrix row reduction to row echelon form to find determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I reduce this matrix to row echelon form and hence find the determinant, or is there a way that I am unaware of that finds the determinant of this matrix without having to reduce it row echelon form given this is all I know and there exists no additional information.

$\left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
   a  & 1 & -1 \\
    a & 2a+2 & a \\
    a-3 & a-3 & a-3 \\
  \end{array}
\right]$

Comment: It's not hard to make 0 two of the three entries on the third row. That reduces the problem to find the determinant of a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: ... and for this purpose it may be simpler to use column operations rather than row operations.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this. One way is to note that 
$$
p(a)=
\begin{vmatrix}
a  & 1 & -1 \\
a & 2a+2 & a \\
a-3 & a-3 & a-3
\end{vmatrix}
$$
is a degree three polynomial. If we find three zeros, then we can find a formula for $p(a)$.

Note that
$$
p(3)=
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 1 & -1 \\
3 & 8 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{vmatrix}=0
$$
so $(a-3)$ divides $p(a)$. Also note that
$$
p(-1)=
\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & -1 \\
-4 & -4 & -4
\end{vmatrix}=0
$$
since the first and third columns are identical. This means $(a+1)$ divides $p(a)$.

Putting this together, we have that
$$
p(a)=(a-3)(a+1)(a-r)
$$
Can you find r?

Answer (score 0):

You may think of the determinant of this matrix as a polynomial of degree $\leq 3$ in $a$. Now there are some values of $a$ that make two rows or two columns identical or one row as a zero row.

For example: if $a=3$, then the last row is zero. What this means is this polynomial will have a factor $(a-3)$. Now try to see if there are other values of $a$ that can make first and third column equal (hence determinant will be zero). That can give you another factor and so on.